# Kibana Data Table nested object counting

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using Kibana version 6.5.1.

**My docs looks like this:**

first

```
{
"id": 12345,
"source": "Github",
"creation_date": "2020-10-14"
"files": [
 {
    "file_id": 444,
    "file_name": "test.png",
    "file_type": "png"
    },
    {
    "file_id": 445,
    "file_name": "test2.pdf",
    "file_type": "pdf"
    },
    {
    "file_id": 446,
    "file_name": "test3.pdf",
    "file_type": "pdf"
  }
]
}
```

second

```
{
"id": 12346,
"source": "stackoverflow",
"creation_date": "2020-10-14"
"files": [
 {
    "file_id": 447,
    "file_name": "example.pdf",
    "file_type": "pdf"
    },
    {
    "file_id": 448,
    "file_name": "anotherOne.pdf",
    "file_type": "pdf"
  }
]
}
```

And so on.

**I want to create data table that looks like this:**

```
file_type | count
------------------
png       | 1
pdf       | 4
```

So in the left we can see the *files.file_type* and in the right the count of each one in all the docs.

I've tried to set a metric of Unique Count of *files.file_id* and Split Rows of aggregation of field *files.file_type.keyword*

But I getting this table:

```
file_type | count
------------------
png       | 3
pdf       | 5
```

And as it looked liked it count all the files in one doc if it has at least one file in the nested 'files' field that matching the file_type.

How could I make it looks like the first table? Would the JSON input at the metric could help?

Comment: did you try the unique count of file_type aggregation?

Comment: @Nejatians Yes in that case it shows 2 pdf and 2 png for two unique type in each doc

Comment: Can you add your mapping please. Your fields are mapped as nested fields ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to map your "files" field as a nested data type to make it work.
Then use a nested aggregation.

A quick example with your sample data:

The mapping:

```
PUT test/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "files": {
      "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

The query:

```
GET test/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "files_nested": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "files"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "files_type": { "terms": { "field": "files.file_type.keyword" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Response:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "files_nested" : {
      "doc_count" : 5,
      "files_type" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "pdf",
            "doc_count" : 4
          },
          {
            "key" : "png",
            "doc_count" : 1
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if there is a way I can put this query on data table visualization?

Comment: with a query you can probably use the _sql endpoint with a ?format=csv but there are some limitations https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html if you want to do this in kibana, unfortunatly, kibana don't manage nested query so you will have to do a transform or to add aggregated data in a specific index to do this